# which packages are required to use make?

Tags: networking, make

I try to compile a package on a fresh debian wheezy inside a VM (32bit Kernel):

```
cd /tmp/
wget https://github.com/freifunk-gluon/batman-adv-legacy/archive/master.zip
rm -Rf batman-adv-legacy-master
unzip master.zip
cd /tmp/batman-adv-legacy-master/
make
make install
```

But I get the error

```
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae/build
Makefile:35: /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae/build is missing, please set KERNELPATH
/tmp/batman-adv-legacy-master/gen-compat-autoconf.sh /tmp/batman-adv-legacy-master/compat-autoconf.h
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae/build M=/tmp/batman-adv-legacy-master PWD=/tmp/batman-adv-legacy-master modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

I also tried:

```
cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/
ln -s /usr/src/batman-adv-2013.4.0/ build
cd -
```

But then I get the error

```
gen-compat-autoconf.sh /tmp/batman-adv-legacy-master/compat-autoconf.h
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae/build M=/tmp/batman-adv-legacy-master PWD=/tmp/batman-adv-legacy-master modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/batman-adv-2013.4.0'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/batman-adv-2013.4.0'
```

I guess I have some packages missing, but which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install the linux headers package for your kernel version. Try something like the following for the metapackage:

```
# apt-get install linux-headers-686-pae
```

On my system (amd64), you can see how the installed header package brings in the `build` directory you're missing:

```
$ dpkg -L linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64 | grep ^/lib/modules
/lib/modules
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/source
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/build
```

I should add that this is in particular to your case because you are trying to compile a kernel module. In general, you will need (besides `make` itself and the compilers for appropriate languages) the header packages for dependencies of the program. In Debian, these are generally found in packages with names like `<project>-dev`.

Comment: Don't you need the `build-essential` package? I would suggest `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential`

Comment: Not necessarily. The description of the [build-essential](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/build-essential) package in Debian says: "If you do not plan to build Debian packages, you don't need this package." You do need some things it depends on, like `gcc`. Installing `gcc` will bring in the C library headers as well. That goes under what I said in my answer-- compilers for appropriate languages. `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` will get you the headers for the kernel you are currently running, but if you upgrade it, you'll have to run this again. The metapackage should track the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the package `build-essential` for compiling packages in debian. Simply execute this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

This will also install some other packages required for compiling (e.g. gcc). This should fix your problem.

Comment: don't you also need `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`?